# Cross referencing Two Tables In Excel

Tags: excel

I have two tables in MS Excel. One is a table indicating the distance between axels of potential gears that can be paired together (multiple columns and multiple rows). The other is a table of positions that axels can be mounted. It also has multiple columns and multiple rows.

How, in Excel, can I identify all cells in one of these sheets that match one or more values anywhere in the other?

For example, is there a way to conditionally format or otherwise indicate when a cell from the second table below contains a number that is in the first table below:

Table 1:
[image: Table 1]

Table 2:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have identical columns in the two sheets, you can use `index(match)` (or `VLOOKUP` but I recommend the first).

If you post a sample of your data I can apply it.

Comment: I've added sample data to the question. I will also look into whether it will be possible to modify the tables so that they have the same number of columns. Will look into index(match) if that turns out to be possible. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please also post your desired output? It is always a good idea to show exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the following and found it successful. Though it only works for cases where the two tables can be put into the same worksheet. And, it is not a very flexible solution. I believe it internally compares for equality, so may not be reliable with floating point numbers.

To conditionally format cells where each single cell of one table is (exactly) present anywhere in another table, you can use countif(). For example, the following returns true or false based on presence of the value of cell A1 within the range $A$16:$G$35:

```
=COUNTIF($A$16:$G$35,A1)>0
```